# delete specific generated div with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to create something like this,
when I click on `submit` each task card add to the Tasks but when I'm trying to **delete** a card for example **task2** by clicking `x` red button
**it first deletes task1 and then task2**

[image]

here is my code I gave the close button an `onclick()` button:

```
'use strict'

const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit')
const inputVal = document.querySelector('.title')
const dateVal = document.querySelector('.date')
let taskDiv = document.querySelector('#task')
submitBtn.addEventListener("click" , function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.classList.add('card')
    card.innerHTML=` 
        <div class="card_top_bar">
            <h3>${inputVal.value}</h3>
            <button id="closeTasks" onclick="closeTask()">x</button>
        </div>
        <span>start : ${dateVal.value}</span>
        <span>end : </span>
        <div class="cardBtnSection">
            <button class="cardBtn" id="minimize"><i class="b bi-dash-circle"></i></button>
            <button class="cardBtn" id="info"><i class="b bi-info-circle"></i></button>
            <button class="cardBtn" id="next"><i class="b bi-check-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
    `
    taskDiv.appendChild(card)
})
function closeTask(){
    let card = document.querySelector(".card")
    card.remove()
}
```

Comment: The "problem" is that `.querySelector` only returns the _first matching element_. What you want to do is add a (unique - of course) ID to each card and pass that ID back into `closeTask` when querying the DOM for a card so that your `closeTask` function finds the _correct_  element, not just _the first one_.

Comment: hi again @David imagine I click the bottom right button and move the card to the `doing` stage how could I handle another click on the same button to  move it to the completed stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue come from `document.querySelector(".card")` it will return the first element that match the selector (here .card) but not necessary the one you need

an idea can be to pass the event as parameter of your function and use target to access clicked button.

To remove all the card you can use `element.closest` to get the closest element match card class

```
function closeTask(event) {
    const card = (event.target || event.srcElement).closest(".card");
    card.remove()
}
```

```js
function closeTask(event) {
  const card = (event.target || event.srcElement).closest(".card");
  card.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <button onclick="closeTask(event)">X</button> card 1
</div>

<div class="card">
  <button onclick="closeTask(event)">X</button> card2
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, mate could you tell me what is event.srcElement?

Comment: on some old browsers as internet explorer event.target is empty and they fill an attribute call srcElement. When i try access event.target i put `?? event.srcElement` for old browser compatibiilty but on all standard, modern browser only target is necessary